# Impute Quarterly data rows

Tags: r, time-series

First time doing TS and I want to calculate a time-series regression but first have to convert my data frame to a ts frame. The problem is, that I have missing quarters, so the ts conversion fails. How can I impute quarters and respective values to get a full ts frame?

Example with quarter 1981.3 missing:

```
1   1981.1  1.2  0.00000000 0   7.881275
2   1981.2 -0.2  1.17870604 0   7.676712
3   1981.4 -0.1  0.00000000 0   7.333129
4   1982.1  0.4  0.00000000 0   7.266816
```

This is the dput.

```
structure(list(Quarter.y = c(1981.1, 1981.2, 1981.4, 1982.1, 
1982.4, 1983.4, 1984.1, 1984.3, 1984.4, 1985.2, 1985.4, 1986.1, 
1986.4, 1987.2, 1987.4, 1988.2, 1988.4, 1989.2, 1989.4, 1990.1, 
1990.2, 1990.4, 1991.2, 1991.4, 1992.2, 1992.4, 1993.2, 1993.3, 
1993.4, 1994.1, 1994.2, 1994.3, 1995.1, 1995.2, 1995.3, 1995.4, 
1996.1, 1996.2, 1996.4, 1997.1, 1997.2, 1997.4, 1998.2, 1998.4, 
1999.1, 1999.2, 1999.4, 2000.1, 2000.2, 2000.3, 2000.4, 2001.1, 
2001.2, 2001.3, 2001.4, 2002.1, 2002.3, 2002.4, 2003.1, 2003.3, 
2003.4, 2004.1, 2004.2, 2004.4, 2005.1), GDPGrowth = c(1.2, -0.2, 
-0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 1.4, 1.3, 2.7, 0.8, 1, 0.6, -0.6, 1, 2.2, 1.6, 
1.8, 1.2, 0.4, 1.2, 2.1, 0.5, 1.8, -0.5, 1.3, -0.7, -0.3, 0, 
0.6, -0.1, 1.4, 0.3, 0.7, -0.3, 0.8, 0.2, 0, -0.8, 1.4, 0.7, 
-0.5, 1.3, 0.7, -0.4, -0.4, 1.2, 0, 0.8, 1.4, 0.8, 0, -0.3, 2, 
0, -0.2, -0.2, -0.5, 0.5, -0.2, -1.5, 0.8, 0.3, -0.2, 0.5, -0.1, 
0), AverageCONS = c(0, 1.17870603993396, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.61936244127144, 
0.416666666666667, 0, 4.32707915240231, 7.6364088578926, 0.257076257076257, 
0, 22.4207759459411, 8.04871523114194, 14.6555459609091, 16.2250782932878, 
1.17084307021898, 6.78706870557528, 0, 0, 9.7539118534683, 0, 
0, 0, 0.0402095172505245, 0, 0, 0.0636265006342972, 0, 0.171974252305606, 
0, 11.1524740312643, 2.68040672020172, 6.2111801242236, 3.24760735460988, 
28.2976799963101, 0, 7.5732270977962, 0, 0, 1.49412278319752, 
70.2064896755162, 34.0042105697558, 18.5823772614653, 18.0896275972026, 
8.41449577357745, 10, 0, 0, 34.7491138493683, 8.36236933797909, 
39.6563615833003, 74.4262295081967, 22.3611248302746, 10, 22.911760840126, 
0, 0.0666722800439236, 0, 50.3843726943174, 0, 0, 1.72909969128655, 
0), BRGOVMEHR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ApprovalGOV = c(7.88127469343306, 7.67671239967451, 
7.33312916270801, 7.26681550104175, 7.57774047678561, 7.44440610328638, 
7.51950710910292, 7.43455364650782, 7.21735906430465, 6.93572597869877, 
7.33281216290814, 7.34110311728404, 7.81953413874152, 7.78638539397364, 
7.5580444419889, 6.70433786365357, 6.76698016084029, 6.9932335657093, 
7.89148017350285, 8.24705859843768, 8.20161269191644, 6.13021112846596, 
7.44587363057623, 7.48928443049876, 6.66476678973035, 6.48625864551226, 
6.13914369458924, 6.05634679973895, 5.9702909369734, 6.19216550005443, 
6.87967122943963, 7.49940214266322, 7.08991191311255, 7.3351806925688, 
7.46762039999888, 7.22336518577119, 6.75192112299076, 6.61614229895973, 
6.39396085192013, 6.09682321355397, 5.99711627005931, 5.95861508444216, 
6.31451929735713, 6.07326509257996, 7.58677238161551, 7.24041796080827, 
6.69547440053917, 7.72437292977251, 7.61985191697131, 7.85861327446016, 
7.78974162557168, 8.00182694049075, 7.82019060836613, 7.58946475073855, 
7.89751118735182, 7.14978411180804, 7.4578134112501, 6.24455242517448, 
5.8823776113788, 6.08103241246385, 5.73879250743035, 5.68128370028589, 
5.83312282222293, 6.49992542902688, 6.45920800878159)), row.names = c(NA, 
-65L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is `dat` then convert that to a zoo object `z` having a `yearqtr` index.  Converting `z` to a `ts` object will insert NAs for the missing entries and then we can use `na.approx` on that to fill in those NAs.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(dat, FUN = function(x) as.yearqtr(paste(x), "%Y.%q"))
na.approx(as.ts(z))
```

### EDIT

Simplified slightly.

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses the `tidyverse` packages to create a new dataframe with 4 rows per each year in your dataset and then uses `left_join` to join your original dataset to that template. This will return NA values for missing quarters in your original data.

**EDIT**: removed assigning data. Data provided is in the `df` object.

```
library(tidyverse)


yrs <- df %>%
  mutate(year = str_replace_all(Quarter.y, "\\.\\d{1}$", "")) %>%
  distinct(year) %>%
  as_vector()

impute <- tibble(yr = as.integer(rep(yrs, 4))) %>%
  group_by(yr) %>%
  mutate(qtr = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(yr, qtr) %>%
  mutate(yr_qtr = paste0(yr, ".", qtr) %>%
           as.numeric()) %>%
  left_join(df, by = c("yr_qtr" = "Quarter.y"))
```

As far as imputing missing values goes, I'm not sure what the right approach here is -- it will depend on what patterns you expect to see/what a reasonable default value is.

Comment: If assigning the data is the same as the original question, you can remove it from your answer. It's really long, and makes the code hard to read—you have to scroll down within the code block to even see your code

Comment: Thanks! Considered that but wasn't sure what was typical. Edited my response.

Comment: Hey, I used the other command, but still thanks alot for taking the time to help!